# Hbitmap from image

Tags: c#, system.drawing

Below creates an image from hbitmap:

```
IntPtr hbitmap = IntPtr.Zero;
...
...
Image img = Image.FromHbitmap(hbitmap);
```

Now I need to do that in reverse, I mean I got an image and want hbitmap to use in method

```
LoadImageFromHBitmap(hbitmap)
```

I save image in memory than load it from there (if someone help). Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for the [`Bitmap.GetHBitmap` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1dz311e4.aspx).
Remember to free the HBitmap.

Comment: guess I was just too slow! This is what comes of knowing nothing about .net and having to look it up myself!